# Finding the path of images pygame

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a game on pygame that displays different Images, and the User should provide the answer to the images through a speech recognization. I had difficulty uploading and displaying images, and I was advised to use a function to load the images, which I did. But now I am having difficulty finding the image files, and I keep getting this error:
[image]

I checked the files locations and the paths and all looks good to me:
[image]
[image][image]

```
import os
import glob
import pygame
import time
import speech_recognition as sr

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
alpha = (0,88,255)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('GUI Speech Recognition')

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'test') 
image_path = os.path.join(resource_path, 'MG') 

#image_list = []
#for filename in glob.glob('MG/*.jpg'):
    #image_list.append(filename)
    


def close():
   pygame.quit()
   quit()

def message_display(text):
   largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30)
   TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
   TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
   gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

   pygame.display.update()


def text_objects(text, font):
   textSurface = font.render(text, True, alpha)
   return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
   mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
   click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
   if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
       pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

       if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
           action()         
   else:
       pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

   smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
   textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
   textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
   gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def load_the_image(image):
    return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,image))

images = [
    load_the_image('cat.jpg'),
    load_the_image('monkey.jpg'),
    load_the_image('dog.jpg')
]

#WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))


def s2t():
  # gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))
   r = sr.Recognizer()

   with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print ('Say Something!')
       audio = r.listen(source)
       print ('Done!')

   text = r.recognize_google(audio)
   print(text)
   
   


   for i in range(len(images)):
      # WINDOW.blit(i)
       if i == 1:
           index=0
           gameDisplay.fill(white)
           carImg = pygame.image.load(images[index])
           pygame.display.update()
           gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
           
           if text == 'cat':
               message_display('good job')
           else:
               message_display('wrong')
               
       elif i== 2:
           index=1
           gameDisplay.fill(white)
           carImg = pygame.image.load(images[index])
           pygame.display.update()
           gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
           
           if text == 'monkey':
               message_display('good job')
           else:
               message_display('wrong')
       elif i== 3:
           index=2
           gameDisplay.fill(white)
           carImg = pygame.image.load(images[index])
           pygame.display.update()
           gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(130,0))
           
           if text == 'dog':
               message_display('good job')
           else:
               message_display('wrong')
               

def main():
   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               quit()
       button("Speak!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,s2t)
       button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,close)
       pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subdirectory "test" is located twice in the image file path.

> `Couldn't open "/User/naifail/Desktop/test/test/MG/cat.jpg"`

But the directory "test" is only contained once in the path of the script file:

> `/User/naifail/Desktop/test/game.py`

Skip the line `resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'test')` :

```py
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'MG')
```

```py
def load_the_image(image):
    return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path,image))
```

Answer (score 0):

What Rabbid76 says works, but it might be another simple error like the image is corrupted or you might have to put the actual path name in your code instead of just cat.jpg.